# How do I test if a Vue method was called using Jest?

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to make a test to see if a method in my Vue app was called on a button press. The relevant code in the main app (Quasar components and classes are used) is:

```
<template>
   <div class="row justify-center inputs">
      <q-input label="Item" v-model="newitem" class="inputbox" outlined></q-input>
      <q-input type="number" label="Quantity" v-model="quantity" class="input2" color="secondary" outlined></q-input>
      <q-btn color="primary" @click="appenditem" class="submit" :disabled="quantity < 1 || newitem.length < 1" no-caps>Add Item</q-btn>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'LayoutDefault',
  components: {
  },
  data () {
    return {
      newitem: "",
      quantity: null,
      array: [],
    }
  },
   methods: {
    appenditem: function() {
          this.array.push({text: this.newitem, quantity: this.quantity});
          this.quantity = null;
          this.newitem = "";
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Inside my test code, I have:

```
import App from "@/App.vue";
import {shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
describe("input-field.vue", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App);
    const append = jest.spyOn(App.methods, "appenditem");
    it("renders", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
    it("title is correct", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toBe("Inventory Manager")
    });
    it("input field loads correctly", () => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.$data.newitem).toBe("")
    });
    it("add button works", () => {
        wrapper.find(".submit").trigger("click");
        expect(append).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

To my knowledge, the variable `append` should spy the appropriate function and then the test should check for whether or not that function is called when an element with the class `submit` is clicked. When I run the tests, it fails and I get the output:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      15 |      it("add button works", () => {
      16 |              wrapper.find(".submit").trigger("click");
    > 17 |              expect(append).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                             ^
      18 |      })
      19 | })
```

What am I missing here? I know the function is being called because the program works.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

The `click`-handler is called in the next tick, so your test should `await` the `trigger("click")` call:

```js
it("add button works", async () => {
  await wrapper.find(".submit").trigger("click");
  expect(append).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```